# I am trying to get response using Retrofit.... onResponses() in not calling

Tags: android, retrofit2

It is not Working When I fatching Data From Server :
**Here is my Class ApiClass**

```
public class ApiClient {
    public static final String BASE_URl="https://simplifiedcoding.net/demos/";
    public  static ApiInterface apiInterface= null;


    public static ApiInterface getApiClient(){
        if (apiInterface == null){

            Retrofit retrofit=new Retrofit.Builder().baseUrl(BASE_URl)
                    .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                    .build();

            apiInterface = retrofit.create(ApiInterface.class); // this line is good
        }
        return apiInterface;
    }
    public interface ApiInterface {
        @GET("marvel/")
        Call<data> getcontex();

    }

}
```

**Here is my Main Class**

```
 Call<data> listcall = ApiClient.getApiClient().getcontex();
            listcall.enqueue(new Callback<data>() {
                @Override
                public void onResponse(Call<data> call, Response<data> response) {
                    data d=response.body();
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Done ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }

                @Override
                public void onFailure(Call<data> call, Throwable t) {
                    Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Faield", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                }
            });
```

**I am seriously can't understand what's wrong. Can you help me guys?**

Comment: try adding a breakpoint to confirm that your `onResponse` is not called. Then check whether your `onFailure` method is getting called, if yes what is the error message thrown in `Throwable`

Comment: did you add internet permision in manifest file.

Comment: Is `Call<data>` the model class is correctly parsed based on the `JSON`

Comment: Can you show your data class ?

Comment: yes i added internet permission @Guruji

Comment: @ShamsSheikh please add your data model with your question.

Comment: error .... java.lang.IllegalStateException: Expected BEGIN_OBJECT but was BEGIN_ARRAY at line 1 column 2 path $

Comment: @ShamsSheikh hey check my answer and let me know if you have any error.

Comment: Thanks it's working Fine :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are having a json array and not a json object, try changing your code like this

```
Call<List<data>> listcall = ApiClient.getApiClient().getcontex();
        listcall.enqueue(new Callback<List<data>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(Call<List<data>> call, Response<List<data>> response) {
                data d=response.body();
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Done ", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(Call<List<data>> call, Throwable t) {
                Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Faield", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });
```

and in your interface

```
 public interface ApiInterface {
    @GET("marvel/")
    Call<List<data>> getcontex();

}
```

Answer (score 0):

I am assuming your api responds with an array of objects and you want to get a callback for that.

```
@GET('your url')
void getData(Callback<ArrayList<Data>> callback);
```

Answer (score 0):

**Try this:-**

Here is your model class

**Data.java**

```
public class Data {

    @SerializedName("name")
    @Expose
    private String name;
    @SerializedName("realname")
    @Expose
    private String realname;
    @SerializedName("team")
    @Expose
    private String team;
    @SerializedName("firstappearance")
    @Expose
    private String firstappearance;
    @SerializedName("createdby")
    @Expose
    private String createdby;
    @SerializedName("publisher")
    @Expose
    private String publisher;
    @SerializedName("imageurl")
    @Expose
    private String imageurl;
    @SerializedName("bio")
    @Expose
    private String bio;

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }

    public String getRealname() {
        return realname;
    }

    public void setRealname(String realname) {
        this.realname = realname;
    }

    public String getTeam() {
        return team;
    }

    public void setTeam(String team) {
        this.team = team;
    }

    public String getFirstappearance() {
        return firstappearance;
    }

    public void setFirstappearance(String firstappearance) {
        this.firstappearance = firstappearance;
    }

    public String getCreatedby() {
        return createdby;
    }

    public void setCreatedby(String createdby) {
        this.createdby = createdby;
    }

    public String getPublisher() {
        return publisher;
    }

    public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
        this.publisher = publisher;
    }

    public String getImageurl() {
        return imageurl;
    }

    public void setImageurl(String imageurl) {
        this.imageurl = imageurl;
    }

    public String getBio() {
        return bio;
    }

    public void setBio(String bio) {
        this.bio = bio;
    }

}
```

---

and interface for api service

**ApiService.java**

```
public interface ApiService {
    @GET("marvel/")
    Call<List<Data>> getHero();
}
```

---

and this is you MainActivity.java

**MainActivity.java**

```
public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity {

    String BaseUrl = "https://simplifiedcoding.net/demos/";
    List<Data> data = new ArrayList<>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

        ApiService retrofitService = new Retrofit.Builder()
                .baseUrl(BaseUrl)
                .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create())
                .build().create(ApiService.class);

        Call<List<Data>> call = retrofitService.getHero();

        call.enqueue(new Callback<List<Data>>() {
            @Override
            public void onResponse(@NonNull Call<List<Data>> call, @NonNull Response<List<Data>> response) {
                data = response.body();
                for (int i = 0; i < data.size(); i++) {
                    //you can get your all data like name,bio,realname,team etc...
                     Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Done", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
                }
            }

            @Override
            public void onFailure(@NonNull Call<List<Data>> call, @NonNull Throwable t) {
                   Toast.makeText(MainActivity.this, "Faield", Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            }
        });

    }
}
```

---

**And last dont forgot to add internet permission in AndroidManifest.xml**

Answer (score 0):

Here I have written working example for your problem. I have found that problem lies in parsing arraylist without key. See below code snippets:

1. Your model class is

   ```
   public class data {
   @SerializedName("name") @Expose private String name;
   @SerializedName("realname") @Expose private String realname;
   @SerializedName("team") @Expose private String team;
   @SerializedName("firstappearance") @Expose private String firstappearance;
   @SerializedName("createdby") @Expose private String createdby;
   @SerializedName("publisher") @Expose private String publisher;
   @SerializedName("imageurl") @Expose private String imageurl;
   @SerializedName("bio") @Expose private String bio;
   public String getName() {
       return name;
   }

   public void setName(String name) {
       this.name = name;
   }

   public String getRealname() {
       return realname;
   }

   public void setRealname(String realname) {
       this.realname = realname;
   }

   public String getTeam() {
       return team;
   }

   public void setTeam(String team) {
       this.team = team;
   }

   public String getFirstappearance() {
       return firstappearance;
   }

   public void setFirstappearance(String firstappearance) {
       this.firstappearance = firstappearance;
   }

   public String getCreatedby() {
       return createdby;
   }

   public void setCreatedby(String createdby) {
       this.createdby = createdby;
   }

   public String getPublisher() {
       return publisher;
   }

   public void setPublisher(String publisher) {
       this.publisher = publisher;
   }

   public String getImageurl() {
       return imageurl;
   }

   public void setImageurl(String imageurl) {
       this.imageurl = imageurl;
   }

   public String getBio() {
       return bio;
   }

   public void setBio(String bio) {
       this.bio = bio;
   }
   ```

   }
2. Then your webservice caller class is:

   public class WebServiceCaller {

   ```
   private static WebServiceApiInterface webApiInterface;
   public static final String BASE_URl = "https://simplifiedcoding.net/demos/";

   public static WebServiceApiInterface getClient() {
       if (webApiInterface == null) {
           HttpLoggingInterceptor logging = new HttpLoggingInterceptor();
           logging.setLevel(HttpLoggingInterceptor.Level.BODY);
           OkHttpClient okclient = new OkHttpClient.Builder().addInterceptor(logging).build();
           Gson gson = new GsonBuilder()
               .setDateFormat("yyyy-MM-dd'T'HH:mm:ssZ")
               .create();


           Retrofit client = new Retrofit.Builder() // .client(okClient)
               .baseUrl(BASE_URl)
               .client(okclient.newBuilder().connectTimeout(10, TimeUnit.MINUTES).readTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS).writeTimeout(100, TimeUnit.SECONDS).addInterceptor(logging).build())
               .addConverterFactory(GsonConverterFactory.create(gson))
               .build();
           webApiInterface = client.create(WebServiceApiInterface.class);
       }
       return webApiInterface;
   }

   public interface WebServiceApiInterface {

       @GET("marvel/")
       Call < ArrayList < data >> getcontex();


   }
   ```

   }
3. Now call service like below in your main activity.

   public void getData() { try {

   ```
       final ProgressDialog dialog = ProgressDialog.show(this, "", "loading...");

       WebServiceCaller.WebServiceApiInterface service = WebServiceCaller.getClient();
       // Call<data> call = service.getStatusMenu("6a10c6fd0a021e8b5beda2948790d9f7FYnx", "com.r3app.wthrcomplete");

       Call<ArrayList<data>> call = service.getcontex();
       call.enqueue(new Callback<ArrayList<data>>() {

           @Override
           public void onResponse(Call<ArrayList<data>> call, Response<ArrayList<data>> response) {
               dialog.dismiss();
               if (response.isSuccessful()) {

                   ArrayList<data> result = response.body();
                   Toast.makeText(ScrollingActivity.this, "Done "+result.get(0).getName(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

               } else {
                   dialog.dismiss();

               }
           }

           @Override
           public void onFailure(Call<ArrayList<data>> call, Throwable t) {
               t.printStackTrace();
               Toast.makeText(ScrollingActivity.this, " "+t.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
               Log.v("onFailure", "onFailure");
               dialog.dismiss();

           }
       });


   } catch (Exception e) {
       e.printStackTrace();
   }
   ```

   }